# $state.go without reload controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to go to another state / route  **without reload state controller**.

I have tried to do the following code :

```
$state.go('mystate', params, {notify: false});
```

but this code not working , and still reload the controller

note : there is no console error

Comment: can you share more code? we cant guess what your doing in the other parts :)

Comment: thanks for ur comment , my controller is more than 4000 line , just my target to change state without reload the controller note: first and second state with the same controller

Comment: Please show me what you put in the params variable :)

Comment: in this case i have no params :)
also i tried to $state.go('mystate', {notify: false});

Comment: Alright, keep this minimal code and then console.log the **$state.get()** and check if "mystate" state is there or not :)

Comment: yes my state is there named ('info')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101952/discussion-between-hasan-daghash-and-smarty-twiti).

Comment: Can you share what the conclusion was?

Answer (score 0):

this is old one but my issue here i think was

the controller reload it self Twice due to angular call the controller two time

first time from the html "ng-controller"

second time from the routing object :

controller : "controllerName"

to solve this remove your ng-controller from the html file .